# mysql - selecting max values in a union

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Given two tables like this:

users

```
+--------+-----------+
| userid | username  |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | username1 |
|      2 | username2 |
|      3 | username3 |
|      4 | username4 |
|      5 | username5 |
+--------+-----------+
```

sessions

```
+--------+-----------+
| userid | timestamp |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |       123 |
|      3 |       321 |
|      5 |       135 |
|      1 |       222 |
|      5 |       333 |
+--------+-----------+
```

I'd like to find the max session timestamp for each user. This looks good so far:

```
select users.username, max(s.timestamp) as timestamp from sessions s
    left join users on s.userid=users.userid group by s.userid
    order by timestamp;

+-----------+-----------+
| username  | timestamp |
+-----------+-----------+
| username1 |       222 |
| username3 |       321 |
| username5 |       333 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

For all users that have no session entry, I'd like to see a `0` for the timestamp, so I try this:

```
select users.username, coalesce(max(s.timestamp), 0) as timestamp from sessions s
    left join users on s.userid=users.userid
union
select users.username, coalesce(max(s.timestamp), 0) as timestamp from sessions s
    right join users on s.userid=users.userid
group by users.userid order by timestamp;
```

Which results in this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| username  | timestamp |
+-----------+-----------+
| username2 |         0 |
| username4 |         0 |
| username1 |       222 |
| username3 |       321 |
| username5 |       333 |
| username1 |       333 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

It looks almost good (users 2 and 4 got 0 as expected), but "username1" got duplicated with the value from a session that actually belongs to "username5".

What causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: You only need the second query from your union statement.

Comment: Thank you, that might have lead me to the solution easily and qualified as an answer even :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `left join` is the right approach.  Just `users` should be the first table:

```
select u.username, coalesce(max(s.timestamp), 0) as timestamp
from users u left join
     sessions s
     on s.userid = u.userid
group by u.username
order by timestamp;
```

Note that I also changed the `group by` keys to match the `select` columns.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed solves it (adding coalesce(max()) on top of it).

Answer (score 3):

Invert the main table (placing user as main tables and not sessione) and check for null
You could use

```
select users.username
 , case when max(s.timestamp) is null then 0 else max(s.timestamp) end  as timestamp 
from users 
left join session  s on s.userid=users.userid
group by user.username
order by timestamp;
```

Comment: Hmm, with this one "username4" is missing in the output.

Comment: Thank you, it works now (changing session->sessions and user->users). Gordon's answer got it right first, so accepted it, but upvoting yours, too.